# Prestrashop - how to add content for Tab in back-office

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Hi i have an issue with prestashop module, I've just created module called TestModule and in install method I got following code:

```
public function install() {
        $parent_tab = new Tab();
        foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
            $parent_tab->name[$lang['id_lang']] = 'TestModule';
        }
        $parent_tab->class_name = 'TestModule';
        $parent_tab->id_parent = 0;
        @copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name . '/logo.png', _PS_IMG_DIR_ . 't/TestModule.png');
        $parent_tab->module = $this->name;
        $parent_tab->add();
        if (!parent::install()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And it created the Tab "TestModule", but when I'm clicking on it there is the information that "Controller not found". How can I set some content here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bellow code , it will help you you made mistake

```
            $langs = Language::getLanguages();
            $id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
            $smarttab = new Tab();
            $smarttab->class_name = "AdminSmartBlog";
            $smarttab->module = "";
            $smarttab->id_parent = 0;
            foreach($langs as $l){
                    $smarttab->name[$l['id_lang']] = $this->l('Blog');
            }
            $smarttab->save();
            $tab_id = $smarttab->id;
            @copy(dirname(__FILE__)."/AdminSmartBlog.gif",_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/img/t/AdminSmartBlog.gif");
```